# Variable being changed mysteriously

Tags: flutter, dart

For some unknown reason, when I run this code and add a note to notesSelected, it changes notesShown.length. (I have checked and notesShown is seemingly not being changed elsewhere without my knowledge, but even if it was being changed elsewhere, I don't see how it could be changed in between these two print statements without me doing it directly).

Any ideas how this could happen in Dart?

I can show more surrounding code if necessary but what I don't get is how surrounding code could change the value of notesShown in between these two print statements.

```
print('notes shown: '+ notesShown.length.toString());
print('notes selected: '+ notesSelected.length.toString());

notesSelected.add(note);

print('notes shown: '+ notesShown.length.toString());
print('notes selected: '+ notesSelected.length.toString());
```

They were declared in the widget as follows:

```
class _ContentTabState extends State<ContentTab> {
  List<Note> notesShown = [];
  List<Note> notesSelected = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

```
Sample pre and post values and output after running this code:

Before:
notesShown = 100
notesSelected = 100

After:
notesShown = 101
notesSelected = 101

Output:
flutter: notes shown: 313
flutter: notes selected: 313
flutter: notes shown: 314
flutter: notes selected: 314
```

Edit:
Jamesdlin's comment below was the fix!

Comment: Are you calling this code inside a build method of a widget?

Comment: It looks interesting. Can you share the surrounding code too?

Comment: This code is contained in a function final void Function(Note) changeNotesSelected that is passed to a child widget. This child widget then calls this function inside its build method.

Comment: I'll see if I can share the surrounding code.

Comment: good catch pskink although no change in result of course

Comment: 2 obvious explanation - 1) it is modified eslewhere, 2) it is called N times.

Comment: If you're observing that `notesShown` is being changed when you mutate `notesSelected`, then somewhere you made both variables reference the same `List` object. You can prove or disprove this by checking `identical(notesShown, notesSelected)`.

Comment: Good one jamesdlin! I ran identical(notesShown, notesSelected) and it resulted in 'true'. Now I just need to find out where I copied the reference but it looks like you identified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not just modify a variable like this inside a stateful widget.
You have to call setState:

```
setState((){
    notesSelected.add(note);
})
```

It might fix the problem.

Comment: Same result if called inside setState (it was my original code actually)